# Prove lower bound on boolean circuit

Tags: complexity-theory, circuits, matrices, boolean-algebra, lower-bounds

Given matrix $A \in \{0,1\}^{n \times m}$ with $n$ rows and $m = 2^n - 1$ columns. Where $j$-th column is binary decomposition of $j$ ($j = 1 \dots 2^n - 1$). For example, if $n = 3$:

$ A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 &0 & 0& 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$

This matrix calculates $Ax$ over $(\{0,1\}, \oplus)$, where $x \in \{0,1\}^m$.

For example, if $n = 3$ it calculates $(x_4 \oplus x_5 \oplus x_6 \oplus x_7,\; x_2 \oplus x_3 \oplus x_6 \oplus x_7, \; x_1 \oplus x_3 \oplus x_5 \oplus x_7)^T$

This is a Boolean function with $m = 2^n - 1$ inputs and $n$ outputs. It can be represented by boolean circuit $S$ with $m = 2^n - 1$ inputs and $n$ outputs, *where only XOR gates are allowed*. **Each XOR gate in circuit $S$ is binary — it takes exactly two inputs**.

Let us denote by $size(S)$ number of gates in $S$ (we don't count inputs as gates, but we count outputs as gates).

It is not hard to prove upper bound: $size(S) \le 2(2^n - 1 - n)$.

> **Problem:** Prove *lower* bound: $size(S) \ge 2(2^n - 1 - n)$.

Comment: There is a highly related survey: https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.671.1024&rep=rep1&type=pdf. They are counting edges in circuits with unbounded fan-in, but some of their bounds are for your model.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, thank you. Yes, I've seen this book. Could you tell me which statement from this book would help me? Because I didn't find something suitable there.

Comment: I haven't thoroughly read the book, but it seems to be a relevant resource.

Comment: Can the same output be reused as input to several XOR gates? If not, isn't the number of XOR gates required trivially the number of ones in the matrix minus $n$?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4084229/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/138349/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: @Ariel If you mean that output of gate can be an input to many gates, than YES. This is possible.